# Crystal Reports Does Not Show Data From View

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Using VS2010, Oracle 11g.

I have a view linking two tables:

```
SELECT table1.Address1, table1.Address2, table1.City, table1.Name
table2.product_name, table1.product_num
FROM table1
inner join table2
on table1.orderid = table2.orderid
```

I can see all the fields from table1 but none from table2.

When I right click on the table2 field and choose "Browse Data", I do see results.

When I click on "Main Report Preview" - I see results.

When I run (F5) I DO NOT see the results, nor when I put the report on the server.

I put some code in the report to tell me that the fields are empty when generated.

Comment: try `ISNULL` option to check whether the field is null

Comment: Nope, it's empty ("").
I do see it when running the SP on SQL Developer.

Comment: when there is no data then how can you expect to show data.. you need to check your query and also if possible fire the query on database if you have access

Comment: But there is data when I run "Main Report Preview" and when I run the query on the database.

Comment: Even when I copy the query from the "Show SQL Query" in Crystal Reports and pasted into the database environment it shows the correct data ....?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I didn't update the object in my code which feeds the report. I guess that since the report is attached to the SP, that's why it showed in "Main Report Preview" but not when running in VS.